# How to decrypt Laravel cookies in Vue

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I attached cookies to the responses.
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/responses#attaching-cookies-to-responses

Then the value of cookies was encrypted https://laravel.com/docs/master/requests#cookies
[image]

***My Laravel code.***

```
return response('Hello World')->cookie('myCookieName', 'MyValue', 0);
```

***Vue using this package*** https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cookies

```
console.log(this.$cookie.get('myCookieName'))
```

console result `eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6Inl1cmlpIiwiZnVsbF9.....`
I'm expected the real value of my cookie. `MyValue`

**How to decrypt or decode the value of cookies to get the real value in Vue?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies` middleware in Laravel allows you to set exceptions. Example:

```php
/**
 * The names of the cookies that should not be encrypted.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $except = [
    'cookie_name',
];
```

For more info checkout the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/responses#cookies-and-encryption).